# Remove indentation from template literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Here is example code, in which I used template literal to create double wrapping around paragraphs:

```
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Bar</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('p').each(function() {
        $(this).wrap(`
            <div class="wrapper1">
                <div class="wrapper2"></div>
            </div>
        `);
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that indentation isn't trimmed, and so, the resulting HTML looks like this:

```
                <div class="wrapper1">                  <div class="wrapper2"><p>Foo</p></div>              </div>
```

This problem doesn't, obviously, apperar when I use traditional way:

```
<script>
    $('p').each(function() {
        $(this).wrap(
            '<div class="wrapper1">' +
                '<div class="wrapper2"></div>' +
            '</div>'
        );
    });
</script>
```

So, is there easy way to remove indentation (spaces, tabs) from template literals?

Comment: Why do you care how the HTML looks like?

Comment: @JJJ To be honest, I don't care much. It was a bit curious, nothing more. Anyway, it could be useful for novice developers, like me, who have similar curiosity on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter, because your `<div class="wrapper1">` get created dynamically with javascript, so there is no result in page speed or anything. It would make sense to remove the indentations in your static HTML file, but it does not matter, if you create DOM elements dynamically

If you want a good pagespeed, i suggest you you minify your js file.

Here are some useful links, that might help you:

- https://www.minifier.org/
- https://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/